# Dynamically editing OrderItem in Order

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.Net Core MVC application there are 2 entities:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

They are stored in the database. Due to the functionality of the application, I may need to change a specific Order along with its corresponding OrderItems.
For this I wrote 2 controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {
            var orderDto = await _orderService.GetOrderWithOrderItemById(id);
            var orderEditViewModel = _mapper.Map<OrderEditViewModel>(orderDto);

            if (orderDto != null)
            {
                return View(orderEditViewModel);
            }

            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(OrderEditViewModel viewModel)
    {
         await _orderService.OrderUpdateAsync(_mapper.Map<OrderDto>(viewModel));

            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Article");
            }

            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }


    }
```

The controllers work correctly, as does the data that should come to them. But my problem is dynamically changing the OrderItem in the Edit view. Now I will provide the full code:

```
    @model OrderEditViewModel

<div class="container">
    <h2>Edit article</h2>
    <div class="row gx-5">
        <form asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Edit" asp-antiforgery="true" method="post">
            <div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" asp-for="Number"></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Number">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" asp-for="Date"></label>
                    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" asp-for="Date">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h5>OrderItems</h5>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            @foreach (var orderItem in @Model.OrderItems)
                            {
                                <div class="offset-2 col-8">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">@orderItem.Name</h5>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            Quantity: @orderItem.Quantity
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                                            Unit: @orderItem.Unit
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="editButton" id="editButton">Edit</button>
                                        <button class="removeButton" id="removeButton">Delete</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            <div id="orderItemsWrapper" class="row gx-5">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="OrderItems[0].Name" />
                                    <input type="text" name="OrderItems[0].Quantity" />
                                    <input type="text" name="OrderItems[0].Unit" />
                                    <a href="#" class="removeButton">Remove</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id="addButton" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Add Order Item</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts
    {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var orderItemsWrapper = document.getElementById("orderItemsWrapper");
            var editButtons = document.querySelectorAll("editButton");
            var addButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
            
            editButtons.forEach(function (editButton) {
                editButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var orderItemDiv = editButton.closest('.order-item');
                    var inputName = orderItemDiv.querySelector('.item-name').textContent;
                    var inputQuantity = orderItemDiv.querySelector('.item-quantity').textContent;
                    var inputUnit = orderItemDiv.querySelector('.item-unit').textContent;

                    var editForm = document.getElementById("editForm");
                    editForm.querySelector("#editItemName").value = inputName;
                    editForm.querySelector("#editItemQuantity").value = inputQuantity;
                    editForm.querySelector("#editItemUnit").value = inputUnit;
                    
                });
            });
            
            addButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var newIndex = orderItemsWrapper.children.length;
                var newOrderItemDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newOrderItemDiv.classList.add("order-item");

                var inputName = document.createElement("input");
                inputName.setAttribute("type", "text");
                inputName.setAttribute("name", "OrderItems[" + newIndex + "].Name");
                newOrderItemDiv.appendChild(inputName);

                var inputQuantity = document.createElement("input");
                inputQuantity.setAttribute("type", "text");
                inputQuantity.setAttribute("name", "OrderItems[" + newIndex + "].Quantity");
                newOrderItemDiv.appendChild(inputQuantity);

                var inputPrice = document.createElement("input");
                inputPrice.setAttribute("type", "text");
                inputPrice.setAttribute("name", "OrderItems[" + newIndex + "].Unit");
                newOrderItemDiv.appendChild(inputPrice);

                var removeButton = document.createElement("a");
                removeButton.setAttribute("href", "#");
                removeButton.classList.add("removeButton");
                removeButton.textContent = "Remove";
                newOrderItemDiv.appendChild(removeButton);

                orderItemsWrapper.appendChild(newOrderItemDiv);
            });
            
            orderItemsWrapper.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (e.target.classList.contains("removeButton")) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.target.parentElement.remove();
                }
            });
        });

                
    </script>

}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not very good at JS. Therefore, I ask for help or advice in writing this functionality. Unfortunately, in my interpretation, the Edit and Delete buttons do not work.
And in general, existing OrderItems are not added to the final model. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "the Edit and Delete buttons do not work" Do you set a breakpoint at the  Edit and Delete  action to see if it excute the action? And you can use `F12` to see if any error messages in the console tab .